# How to resolve "Cannot find module" Error when testing react components with mocha

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, react-dom, react-test-renderer

In all my components i have imported other components like

```
import PrevArrow from 'components/Slider/PrevArrow';
```

when I want to test a component I always get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'components/Slider/PrevArrow'
```

because it assumes the wrong path. 
Right import method would be

```
import PrevArrow from '../../components/Slider/PrevArrow';
```

with this the test passes, but I dont want to refactor all components just because of this.

Is there a way that i can leave my import statements as they are and still get my test passed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know those tools specifically, but can you link the components directory into the module search root? E.g., `ln -s ../../components .`?

Comment: unfortunately that didnt help either

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-root-slash-import) plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is because we are using webpack in our codebase.

So mocha will not work as it should. 
I needed to install

```
npm install --save-dev mocha-webpack
```

and rewrite my test script in package.json from

```
"test": "mocha './build/**/*.test.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ignore-styles"
```

to

```
"test": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config webpack.config.js './build/**/*.test.js'"
```

and now it works